# I can not create simple Angular Project with either from Powershell or from VsCode

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, powershell, visual-studio-code

I started to learn Angular Cli with my new job and I was listening tutorials.

I could not create a simple app using "ng new HelloApp, cd HelloApp, npm start" in powershell, then VS Code terminal which gave me error which I learned package.json has not been created. I manually created it and used "npm init,npm install" which gave me some warnings. Regardless if I use "npm audit fix" or not I receive "An unhandled exception occurred: Could not find the implementation for builder @angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server" error.

I installed Node.js , WebStorm , Visual Studio Code and Angular Cli new versionsi

Here is my package.json then my version list;

```
{
  "name": "hello-app",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "~7.2.0",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "rxjs": "~6.3.3",
    "tslib": "^1.9.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.12.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~8.3.5",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "~7.2.0",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "codelyzer": "~4.5.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~3.1.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.11.0",
    "typescript": "~3.2.2"
  }
}
```

.
npm version:

```
npm: '6.11.3',
  ares: '1.15.0',
  brotli: '1.0.7',
  cldr: '35.1',
  http_parser: '2.8.0',
  icu: '64.2',
  modules: '64',
  napi: '4',
  nghttp2: '1.39.2',
  node: '10.16.3',
  openssl: '1.1.1c',
  tz: '2019a',
  unicode: '12.1',
  uv: '1.28.0',
  v8: '6.8.275.32-node.54',
  zlib: '1.2.11' }
```

.

ng version :

```
Angular CLI: 8.3.5
Node: 10.16.3
OS: win32 x64
Angular:
...

Package                      Version
------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect    0.803.5
@angular-devkit/core         8.3.5
@angular-devkit/schematics   8.3.5
@schematics/angular          8.3.5
@schematics/update           0.803.5
rxjs                         6.4.0
```

.

tsc -v : TS6029: Version 1.5.3

Comment: What does happen when you run `ng new MyProject` ?

Comment: From a command line or editor. Do not know even if it is matters.

Comment: From a command line or editor. Do not know even if it is matters. Asks if I want to Angular routing which I select "No", then I choose css, giving me  10 warning about  skipping optional dependecy. 1 Example is :npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.9 (node_modules\webpack-dev-server\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.9: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

Comment: Warnings aren't errors you know ! If you have no error, then you should have created your application, so what's the issue exactly ?

Comment: npm start then this "An unhandled exception occurred: Could not find the implementation for builder @angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server"

Answer (score 0):

I'd definitely suggest to try this, What have worked for me was:

```
1.) Make sure your angular version starts with 7.2.15 (if not, you should install this version first)
2.) Be sure your Node version is 12.x.x
3.) Typescript version 3.4.5
3.) ng update @angular/cli @angular/core (for @angular/cli, be sure to install it both local & global)
4.) npm uninstall @angular-devkit/build-angular
5.) npm install @angular-devkit/build-angular
6.) ng update --all
7.) If you have ViewChild on your application, be sure to edit them with: Source

@ViewChild(<name>, {static: true}) <name>; // Adding static: true on the 2nd param
```

**Step 7:**

```
Before:

@ViewChild('foo') foo: ElementRef;

After:

// query results available in ngOnInit
@ViewChild('foo', {static: true}) foo: ElementRef;

OR

// query results available in ngAfterViewInit
@ViewChild('foo', {static: false}) foo: ElementRef;
```

[More Info](https://angular.io/guide/static-query-migration)

Comment: I did not understand the step 7, can you elaborate if you do not mind, I am new at this ^^

Comment: Updated my comment, if you need more info checkout the reference doc.. @bkardo

Comment: Thank you very much, I will try tomorrow ^^

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1 :** npm install -g @angular/cli

**Step 2 :** npm install -g @angular/cli@7.x.x   Update the version as per your requirement.

**Step 3 :**

- ng new PROJECT-NAME
- cd PROJECT-NAME
- ng serve

For more details please visit the below url.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular/cli

Comment: Shouldn't new versions come with less bugs, why do I have to downgrade the version? I don't judge your advice don't get me wrong please, I just understand these version problems at all.